# Get all post data from request

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to get all the POST data sent to a .NET webpage?

Basically I am looking for the equivalent of the PHP $_POST array

The purpose being that I am receiving requests from a client that I have no control over and need to get all the data without knowing they keys.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
foreach(string name in Request.Form)
{
    Response.Write(Request.Form[name]);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get it when there is no form ?

Comment: @ChuckNorris, you're probably talking about query string arguments; try replace `Request.Form` with `Request.QueryString`

Comment: no, it's also empty, I'm posting from flash using NetConnection, here's the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10519617/112100

Answer (score 4):

You want `Request.Form`  There's a keys collection in there you can iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.ToString()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33447748)

Answer (score -3):

You can use `return Request.Form.ToString();` to get raw POST data.

Comment: Wont this just print out the class name of `Dictionary`?