# use amf remoting with asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, actionscript-3, flash, amf

anybody knows if it is possible to do calls from flash to asp.net mvc actions using amf remoting ?

if yes, how? which technologies should be used and how to combine them

on the flash side it would be something like this:

```
    //Connect the NetConnection object
    var netConnection: NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    netConnection.connect("http://localhost:59147/Home/Index");

   //Invoke a call
   log("invoke call TestMethod");
   var responder : Responder = new Responder( handleRemoteCallResult, handleRemoteCallFault);
   netConnection.call('TestMethod', responder, "Test");
```

I tried this and it hits the action but I can't find the 'TestMethod' and "Test" anyware in the Request

Thank You

Comment: did you try to use .NET client AMF libraries, there is a list on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format#Support_for_AMF

Comment: @AntonioBakula I tried FluorineFx but it works with RemoteObjects only, I can't change the flash side and it uses NetConnection the way I showed above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but this could help you in the start.

You could use FluorineFx, that is a good start as it implements all the AMF stuff and it has AMFWriter/Reader, AMFDeserializer and so, play with them.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FluorineFx.IO;

public class AMFFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType == "application/x-amf")
        {
            var stream = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;

            var deserializer = new AMFDeserializer(stream);
            var message = deserializer.ReadAMFMessage();

            foreach (var body in message.Bodies) // not foreach, just the first one
            {
                filterContext.ActionParameters["method"] = body.Target;
                filterContext.ActionParameters["args"] = body.Content;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}

[AMFFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string method, object[] args)
{
    return View();
}
```

This is just the first part. Returning binary data and stuff could be handled by some kind of custom ActionResult, but that one you know how to do from here [AMF ActionResult for asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974392/amf-actionresult-for-asp-net-mvc) ?

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, it works, except when I send an object I get a dictionary at the c# side, do you know if it's possible to make deserialize into an object ?

Comment: ok, found this one, I used this: http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/classmappingas3.html and now it maps the as object to .net

Comment: @ChuckNorris class mapping and aliases, yes! and you can save some traffic when using custom serialization via IExternalizable (however not your case when you can't change client side)